# Centering a dropdown menu on the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a top bar dropdown-menu in my bootstrap homepage.
The dropdown-menu starts under each menuitem.
I want to center the dropdownmenu on the page. (should start on the left side and end on the right side of my content-area which is 1280px)

HTML:

```
        <div class="navbar">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container" style="width: 1280px;">
              <ul class="nav" role="navigation">
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a id="drop1" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle menuitem" data-toggle="dropdown">nav1</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="drop1" style="width:1180px;">
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://google.com">Action</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#anotherAction">Another action</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: And CSS?? May be a fiddle??

Comment: CSS is the standard css from bootstrap. Nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

you can get your container to be `relative`, get your `li.dropdown` to be absolute with `left:0`.

CSS:

```
.container{
    position:relative;
}

li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu{
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0 /*according to your menu height */
    width: 1280px;
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
I tried to add your code but the dropdown is still under each menuitem.

if i set "left: - 100px", for example, it is 100px on the left side.
But I need to get it dynamically because each menuitem has a different margin to the left side.

Comment: if your container is relative, and your top menu (`li.dropdown') isn't, then the `dropdown-menu`  will take the container as placement and `left:0` will always start from the left edge of the container. Your `li.dropdown-down` menu should not have any padding or margin if you want all of them to be the same width (1280px)